# Assets 2, no files displayed

Tags: add-on, assets

New to P&T Assets, just got it today, v2.  Using a flat out blank template and the two examples from the site docs.  Scanned two directories of images that work in the normal file manager.  It appears the assets:files tag displays nothing.  assets:folders Folders display.  EE2.5.5.

```
{exp:assets:folders folder="top" recursive="yes"}
    <h3>{folder_name}</h3>
    <ul>
        {exp:assets:files folder="{folder_id}"}
            <li><a href="{url}" target="_blank">{if title != ""}{title}{if:else}{filename}{/if}</a></li>
        {/exp:assets:files}
    </ul>
{/exp:assets:folders}
```

Shows:

#### Image

#### Screenshots

Should it show the list of files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you indexed your upload directories according to the [**Assets docs**](http://pixelandtonic.com/assets/docs)?

> ***Assets won’t actually show any files until you’ve indexed your upload
>   directories. You can do that from Add-Ons → Modules → Update Indexes.***
>   The initial indexing might take some time, depending on how many files
>   you have. However future indexes should go much quicker, since Assets
>   will only have to index what’s changed.
>
> You can also re-index an individual folder by clicking the “Refresh”
>   button at the top-right of Assets’ file manager, or from its
>   fieldtype’s file selection modal.

Comment: I believe their example has a typo.

{exp:assets:files folder="{folder_id}"}

Should actually be...
{exp:assets:files folder_id="{folder_id}"}

Comment: Does changing that parameter name get things working?

Comment: Yep it does.  Shot them a tweet, fixed on their site.

Comment: Tada! Can you add this as your answer and accept it as correct by clicking on the check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Changing `folder="{folder_id}"` to `folder_id="{folder_id}"` got things working correctly.